# I am not able to delete items in my todo list made with react, please help me with error in my code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frameworks, web-development-server, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

below is my code for todo list i am not able to delete items in my list in delete items function please help me with error.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const change1 = (e) => {
    setInputList(e.target.value);
  };
  const change2 = () => {
    setItems((oldItems) => {
      return [...oldItems, inputList];
    });
    setInputList("");
  };
  const deleteItem = (ind) => {
    return setItems(items.filter((item)=>{return item.ind!==ind}))
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="inner_div">
        <h1 style={{ borderBottom: "2px solid black" }}>ToDo List</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange={change1} value={inputList} />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button onClick={change2}>+</button>
        <ol style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
          {items.map((itemval, ind) => {
            return (
              <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <button onClick={deleteItem}>-</button>&nbsp;
                <li id={ind}>{itemval}</li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!
This should work

Items does not have any ind properties.
Index is the second parameter of the filter and you must use it in the filter to remove,
and you have to pass the index in the function deleteItem (ind).

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 import "./styles.css";

  export default function App() {
   const [inputList, setInputList] = useState("");
   const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
   const change1 = (e) => {
   setInputList(e.target.value);
 };
 const change2 = () => {
 setItems((oldItems) => {
  return [...oldItems, inputList];
 });
 setInputList("");
};
const deleteItem = (ind) => {
return setItems(
  items.filter((item, i) => {
    return i !== ind;
   })
  );
 };
  return (
   <div className="App">
   <div className="inner_div">
    <h1 style={{ borderBottom: "2px solid black" }}>ToDo List</h1>
    <input type="text" onChange={change1} value={inputList} />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button onClick={change2}>+</button>
    <ol style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
      {items.map((itemval, ind) => {
        return (
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <button onClick={() => deleteItem(ind)}>-</button>&nbsp;
            <li id={ind}>{itemval}</li>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are passing the click event to the `deleteItem` handler.

```
const deleteItem = (ind) => { // <-- click event object!
  return setItems(items.filter((item)=>{return item.ind!==ind}))
}

...

<button onClick={deleteItem}>-</button>
```

There is also an issue with your filter function, you are comparing the index to a property on the items and this condition will almost always be false and clear the `items` array.

```
(item)=>{return item.ind!==ind}) // item.ind is undefined
```

## Solution

Fix the `deleteItem` handler to correctly compare indices.

```
const deleteItem = (index) => {
  setItems(items => items.filter((item, i)=> i !== index));
}
```

You need to pass the mapping index value to the callback. Don't forget to add an unique React key to the mapped elements. Since you've no GUIDs on the item elements the array index will have to do for now.

```
{items.map((itemval, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={ind} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <button onClick={() => deleteItem(index)}>-</button>&nbsp;
      <li id={index}>{itemval}</li>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

If you want to avoid the anonymous function in the button's `onClick` handler you can convert `deleteItem` to a curried function and enclose/close over the specific todo's index value. A function is returned to serve as the `onClick` callback.

```
const deleteItem = (index) => () => {
  setItems(items => items.filter((item, i)=> i !== index));
}

...

<button onClick={deleteItem(index)}>-</button>
```

Comment: this is working but not the way i want when i click on minus to delete the item it deletes all the values that i have added i only want to delete the item which i click not all.can you give more accurate code?

Comment: @NamanVerma Oh, I see what is happening. When you add items to your `items` state you are adding strings, but these won't have an `ind` property. I see now you likely were trying to use the mapped index. I updated my answer, please take another look. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Delete Functionality:

```
const deleteItem = (ind) => {
 const newDeleteData =[...items];
 newDeleteData.splice(ind,1);
 setItems(newDeleteData);
 };
```